# F# - How to call C# overridden methods with exact same named arguments

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

How to call C# overridden methods with exact same named arguments?

Example

```
public static Task<CreateImageSummaryModel> CreateImagesFromDataAsync(this ITrainingApi operations, Guid projectId, IEnumerable<Stream> imageData, IList<Guid> tagIds = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken));



public static Task<CreateImageSummaryModel> CreateImagesFromDataAsync(this ITrainingApi operations, Guid projectId, Stream imageData, IList<string> tagIds = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken));
```

Same method name and argument names, but args have different signatures.

Now trying to call first method

```
let uploadStreams (tag: string) (streams: Stream seq) (projectId: Guid) (trainingApi: TrainingApi) = 

    let tag = trainingApi.CreateTag(projectId, tag)

    let tags = new List<_>([tag.Id])

    let streams = streams :> IEnumerable<Stream>

    trainingApi.CreateImagesFromDataAsync(projectId, imageData = streams, tagIds = tags)
```

This gives compilation error

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   FS0001  The type 'IEnumerable<Stream>' is not compatible with the type 'Stream' 

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   FS0193  Type constraint mismatch. The type     'IEnumerable<Stream>'    is not compatible with type    'Stream' 

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   FS0001  The type 'List<Guid>' is not compatible with the type 'IList<string>'   VisionAPI
```

Usually when I deal with overridden methods in F# I just use explicit argument names such as

```
let x = cls.someOverriddenMethod(arg1 = 1)
```

But in this case this not works.

How should I proceed in this case ?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you update your example method call with the one that you're actually trying to call (`CreateImagesFromDataAsync`) and include the compiler error message.

Comment: Although you don't show what `CreateImagesFromData` looks like, given that `CreateImagesFromDataAsync` requires tags of type `Guid` or `string` and you appear to have a tag of type `Models.Tag`, I suspect this is just a simple typo on this parameter.

Comment: Thank you, yes in tag was typo, I modified this, but this is not a root problem here. Main problem persists - F# couldn't inference correctly overridden method type

Answer (score 3):

I think the issue is that `imageData` is not an optional parameter, but you're passing it like it is one.  Just pass `streams` directly instead of using `imageData = streams`.  Here's a minimal working example that compiles for me:

```
open System
open System.IO

type MyType () =
    static member A(a: string, b: Guid, c: Stream seq, ?d: Guid list) = ()
    static member A(a: string, b: Guid, c: Stream, ?d: Guid list) = ()

let f (streams: Stream seq) guids =
    MyType.A("", Guid.Empty, streams, d = guids)
    MyType.A("", Guid.Empty, streams |> Seq.head, d = guids)
```

Answer (score 0):

Happens  these definitions were taken from CustomVision API 1.0

```
public static Task<CreateImageSummaryModel> CreateImagesFromDataAsync(this ITrainingApi operations, Guid projectId, IEnumerable<Stream> imageData, IList<Guid> tagIds = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken));



public static Task<CreateImageSummaryModel> CreateImagesFromDataAsync(this ITrainingApi operations, Guid projectId, Stream imageData, IList<string> tagIds = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken));
```

And my F# app use version API 1.2 in which first method is no longer exists (which is strange)

At least mystery solved.